# jQuery Mobile Collapsible with nested Listview does not display correctly

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I'm new to jQueryMobile and forcing a problem I cannot solve alone.

I'm having a HTML form, which is very large (~100 fields). To improve usability the form is divided into 4 parts, which are on 4 JQM-pages. On each page I have the same menu with a collapsible-set displaying the users. If you click on a user you can see the reports for each user (which is the listview).

On `$(document).ready` - event I'm calling a `load_users` function to retrieve all users and their reports from the database. With these data I build up the collapsible and listviews and at the end I call 
    `$(".listview:visible").listview().listview("refresh");
    $(".menu:visible").collapsibleset("refresh");`
to display the collapsibles and listviews correctly. Because the menu is build on all four pages simultanously, I had to add the :visible-pseudoclass.

The problem occurs now when I insert a new user to the database. The insertion is working fine. After that I remove all elements from the menu and call again `load_users()` to populate the menu again. But what worked before is ending up in a plain list without the expected styling.

Can anyone give me a hint how I can make JQM make my collapsible and listviews display correctly?

Comment: The first time you create the listview you call the `.listview()`  method (by itself, the refresh method is unnecessary), after that when you are just updating it you should be **only** calling it's refresh method (`.listview('refresh')`).

Comment: @jack because he is re-inserting the whole listview again, he will need to call the .listview() constructor which will recreate the widget. If he was just updating the li's .listview('refresh') alone would be ok.

Comment: @DalSoft I initially understood that he was emptying the listviews and reinserting the elements, but rereading his question it looks like he is recreating the entire listview.

Comment: DalSoft is right. I remove the whole collapsible and the neseted listviews. This way I can call load_clients any time and do not have to worry if a user had be inserted, deleted or updated.

Comment: dont use `.ready()`. To enhance collapsible-set use `.collapsibleset().trigger('create');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add html manually in jQuery Mobile you need to tell it to re-do the enhancements that were done during page create.

To do this call the `.listview()` constructor which will recreate the widget rather than `.listview('refresh')` which will just refresh. Also make sure that when you re-create any markup that you add the data-role attribute.

Lastly don't use $(document).ready it will cause problems with JQM navigation instead use `$('#mypageid').on('pageinit', function(){});`

http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/

Comment: It seems that .listview() and/or .collapsible('refresh') does not work properly if used across pages. I changed the code so that the collapsible and listviews are only created on the active page.